# Meaning of icon in open street map?

Tags: icons, openstreetmap

I'm curious what the representational difference is between these two religious icons:
[image]

The cross clearly represents a christian church. 

Is the kneeling person icon used to represent a more general religious building that isn't necessarily a church and/or christian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [OpenStreeMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:religion), it is a generic symbol for place of worship. As you have "Christian" in the name of your example, religion category of this POI should be set to christian - it is none right now, what can be easily checked using [Query feature](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/358849890).